# Dispatcher.Invoke on application idle on button click - does my UI freeze/block

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

Imagine you have some routine that registers as BeginInvoke to the ApplicationIdle, for example

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Action)OffLoadWork);
```

Now in certain scenarios this OffLoadWork needs to be executed when doing a operation in the UI, for example on a button click, is it safe for me to call

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (Func<object>)(() =>
{
    //do nothing just wait for the OffLoadWork to happen...
    return null;
}));
```

or can it occur that my UI freezes, since I am in the middle of an UI Operation so when does it actually get Idle?

In my first test, it seemed to work but I just want to make sure that there isn't a way for it to freeze/block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle`. Invoke is sync and can block your UI.

`DispatcherPriority` here as per the definition is the priority, relative to the other pending operations in the `Dispatcher` event queue, the specified method is invoked. So if your operation is the only one happening in the Dispatcher queue and triggered on UI thread it will block it till the time it does not return.

Comment: I know that the Invoke method is sync and there for block by nature, my question more refers to can it block for ever since the state of ApplicationIdle may never raise since I am in a UI operation so why should it get Idle when I am currently running code in the UI?!?

Comment: This is not actually ApplicationIdle, it just tells the relatavity. So if you have other operations with more priority in Dispatcher queue those will be invoked first and then this operation will be picked once those operation are done.

Comment: So to get this right, the Priority ApplicationIdle doesn't actually mean that the Application is idle (as doing nothing) in that moment, its just a "key" that says do everything in the queue below that key and if done go on?

Comment: Sort of, but if you already have everything done, u can say that application is idle in that situation :)